# Doesn't this LED created by MIT violate the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, entropy, light-emitting-diodes

Here is the article I am referring to: http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-03/09/230-percent-efficient-leds

In their own words (or at least the article writer's), "it appears to draw in heat energy from its surroundings ... it begins to cool down, stealing energy from its environment to convert into more photons."

Well, there we have it. In the simplest case, you could use this device to pump heat from cold to hot, by simply aiming the light from the LEDs onto a dark surface. This obviously shouldn't be possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: The article has its own definition of "efficiency", which has nothing to do with actual thermodynamic efficiency.